# Ackermann function and Hierarchy question

Tags: algorithms

**Question:**

> Ackermann Hierarchy defined as following: $$A_{k}(n)=A_{k-1}^{(n)}(1), \ k\geq2, \ A_1(n)=2n$$
> In addition, Ackermann function defined as following: $$A(n)=A_n(3)$$
>
> **A.** which of the following grows faster to infinity? $A_7(A_4(n))$ or  $A_4(A_7(n))$.
>
> B. suppose we want to find a function that grows faster than $A(n)$, therefore, we
> define this function to be $B(n)=A_n(100)$. Prove that B(n) doesn't grow much faster than $A(n)$, i.e. prove that there is a constant $c$ such that: $\forall n :A(n+c)\geq B(n)$.

---

$Solution.A.$

Proof by induction on $n$ that $\forall n\geq 2: A_4(A_7(n))<A_7(A_4(n))$, which is a more powerful claim.

Basis. for $n=2$: $$A_4(A_7(2)) = A_4(4)< A_7(A_4(2)) = A_7(4)$$

Step. suppose that the claim is correct for $n-1$ and we will prove it for $n$. Therefore, $$A_4(A_7(n-1)) < A_7(A_4(n-1))$$

Hence, $$A_7(A_4(n)) = A_{6}^{A_4(n)}(1)= A_{6}^{A_{3}^{(n)}(1)} =A_{6}^{A_{3}{(1)}}(A_{6}^{A_{3}^{(n-1)}(1)}) = A_{6}^{A_{3}{(1)}}(A_7(A_4(n-1))) > A_{6}^{A_{3}{(1)}}(A_4(A_7(n-1)))$$

when the last inequality is according to the I.H.

since, $$A_{6}^{A_3(1)} = A_{6}^{2}(n) > A_{3}^{A_6(1)} = A_{3}^{2}(n)$$

then: $$A_{6}^{A_{3}{(1)}}(A_4(A_7(n-1))) > A_{3}^{A_{6}{(1)}}(A_4(A_7(n-1))) = A_4(A_7(n)). \ Q.E.D.$$

$Solution.B.$

Proof by induction on $n$ that $\forall n \exists c:A(n+c)\geq B(n)$.

For the basis, let $n=1$ and there is a constant $c=3$ such that: $$
65536 = A_3(3) = A_{c+1}(3) = A(c+1) \geq B(1) = A_1(100) = 200$$

Step. suppose that the claim is correct for $n-1$ and we will prove it for $n$. Thus, there is
a constant c such that:
$$A(( n-1) +c)\geq B(n-1)$$

Therefore, $$A(n+c)=A_{( n-1) +c}^{2}( A(( n-1) +c)) \geq A_{( n-1) +c}^{2}( A_{n-1}( 100)) \geq A_{( n-1) +c}( 100)\underbrace{\geq }_{c\ \geq \ 1} A_{n}( 100) =B(n)$$

So we can actually pick the same constant $c$. $Q.E.D.$

---

I will be glad if you can tell me whether solutions A and B are correct or not, if not so tell me why.

- In both solutions I find it hard to make the step, and it seems that
  what I am doing is big nonsense. In solution B, it seems strange that
  I can peak the same constant and not a new constant but if I do
  otherwise, I can't succeed in proving the statement for $n$. Solution
  A seems to be true, but I don't know if the steps are allowed with
  Ackerman hierarchy.

Thanks!

---

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: yes of course I can. I will edit, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Nathaniel Edited...

Comment: I don't know what "hard to make the step" means.  If you're asking whether a specific step is valid, please indicate which step, and why you are asking.  Right now it appears you're just asking us to verify your approach, which is a kind of question we discourage.  Do you have a more specific question you can articulate than "is my solution correct?"  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to do the work to articulate a specific, focused question that can be answered concisely and will be useful to others.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/147913/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4340270/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. I am sorry I forgot to delete the previous post. 
Well, I am not repeating myself, since I told what the problem with the solution
B. It seems strange that I can pick the same constant I used with the I.H, so I don't know if it's logically correct to do so.  The way I proved the induction step in solution B seems not on point.

Comment: Please pick one solution you want to ask about, and one step that you want to ask about, and narrow your question to ask about that.  Please articulate a question very clearly.  Right now your post ends with some vague statements and I find it hard to tell what exactly your question is.

Comment: Well, I wanted to focus on solution B, since the induction step there was more complex for me. I picked c as a constant that satisfies the statement for n-1, now when I want to prove for n it seems that I can use the same constant, and then I get that is correct. It is hard to explain, but it doesn't seem logically right to prove the step like I did. Therefore, I asked for clarification there.